# Using scala-native for in-memory data processing

Tags: scala-native

I'm wondering whether it is possible to leverage scala-native for performing large in-memory jobs.

For instance, imagine you have a spark job that needs  150GB of RAM so you'd have to run 5x30GB executors in a spark cluster since JVM garbage collectors wouldn't catch up with heap bigger than that.

Imagine that 99% of the data being processed are `Strings` in collections.

Do you think that scala-native would help here? I mean, as an alternative to Spark?

How does it treat `String`? Does it also have this overhead because jvm treats it as class?

What are the memory ("Heap") GC limits as the classic 30GB in case of JVM? Would I also end up with a limit like 30GB?

Or is this generally a bad idea? To use scala-native for in-memory data processing. My guess is that [scala-offheap](https://github.com/densh/scala-offheap) is better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

in-memory data processing is a use case where scala-native will shine compared to Scala on JVM.

SN supports all types of memory allocations. Static allocation (you can define the global variable in C and return a pointer to it with a C function), stack allocation, dynamic allocation based on C malloc/free and garbaged dynamic allocation (Scala new).

For Strings, you can use 8 bits per char C String, Java style 16 bits per char or you can implement you own Small String Optimization as seen in C++, using @struct and pointers.

Of course, you have temporal drawbacks, like SN still a pre 0.1 version and lack of Java library being ported to Scala.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment it is a bad idea because of Scala Native not ready for production use. Also, Scala Native uses garbage collector(now BOEHM) and will see same problems like with a JVM, but with Scala Native, you can try manual memory management.